# JQuery - Using Wildcards to find text

Tags: jquery, html, replace, wildcard

I have a plugin which is replacing the body of a message with a new body, which appends an id to it, for example:
I sent the body "Is anyone here?".
The plugin intercepts and replaces it with:

```
"Question from "+ id + ":\n\"" !body! "\""
```

What I need to do, is replace the id with a name in certain cases.

My hope is to do as follows:

```
var newBody = body.replace("Question from " + * + ":", "Question from " <name> ":");
```

So I am trying to say, if the body says "Question from ", following by anything, but ending at ":", replace it.

This is not working though, it is saying the "*" is invalid. Is my plan possible?

Comment: [REGEX](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), [RegEx Obj](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp), [SO RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not separate your concerns into different elements?

```
"<h1>Question from: "+id+"</h1>
<p>"+body+"</p>"
```

Then you simply need to do

```
$('h1').html('Question from: '+newID);
```

Comment: I did try this before, but my access to the plugin source is not 100% (plus I'm not very good at coding java), and I couldn't manage to split it using just JQuery/Javascript.

Comment: I'll vote this as the answer as it is the best solution. In the end I had to change the plugin code to do this as nothing in jquery/javascript was sufficient, but thanks for the response.